# Is there a way to restrict individual user access to plugins in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to restrict access to plugins for a specific user. I still want this user to be able to edit the theme, but it should not be able to modify plugins or update wordpress.

I did a little research and don't think that there's a simple way to allow this, but before I go along the path of finding a plugin to support this feature, I wanted to ask and make sure there wasn't the ability to do this out of the box.

Comment: Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will only grant permission to edit the theme in the WordPress Admin Panel. While plugins may be able to restrict editing plugins in the same manner, using this feature at all is highly dangerous as all changes are effective immediately on a live server and can be extremely destructive. If the user's account is compromised someone can directly inject malicious code into the files.

Any changes to theme code, or plugin code for that matter, should be done on local copies of files and then uploaded to the server.

In all of my WordPress installations, even my local development environments, I put the following line of code in my wp-config.php file:

```
define(‘DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT’, true)
```

This disables the editor in the WP Admin Panel.